# How to find the small and big id in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here the Situation . I am having 2 million records in table .

Just consider the contacts tables has id filed. and id has different number . But now i want to find the smallest and largest id   from contacts table .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT min(id_field),max(id_field) FROM table;
```

This will work for both tables.

Answer (score 4):

you're looking for [min](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_func_min.asp) and [max](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp).

```
SELECT min(id),max(id) FROM table;
```